# Angular Routing: Does an app feature module is allowed to know routing config from an other lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading

our App is separated into several lazy loaded feature modules. Each module get's loaded under different path matches. We also have the case that some modules are importing a shared module containing reusable components and so on. Sounds ok so far :)

We now have the case that for example module-A and module-B are using the same shared-module, using from there a component which emit some outputs where the host want to trigger routing navigation. In that case module-A want's to trigger a routing on a deeper nested path where module-B with internal sub-paths is configured for. So we can simply call the router navigate with the concrete path to module-B and all will work.

BUT somehow it feels weird to let a foreign domain (module-A) know about routing config stuff of an other domain (module-B). Are there any ideas to keep the routing config in module-B in secret so that module-A is not allowed to know the routing config from module-B?

Understandable? I hope so, THX :)

Comment: Lazy-loaded modules are not intended to keep th routing secret. They are only intended to be loaded later. Routing config is not more secret in a lazy loaded module than in any other module.

Comment: Sounds acceptable :) BUT what's the case when these lazy modules came from remote domains in conext of micro-frontends. So each MFE is running on it's own domain and hosted code/repository separately by different teams. Would we assume here that they will exchange about their modules internal routing config?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right - module A shouldn't know about specific routes from module B. These modules should act as a separate parts of the application and they shouldn't communicate with each other.

You can approach this problem by dispatching some sort of general action or event (e.g. ngrx action) and handling it in the parent scope (where the routing is defined).

In that case module A would know nothing about module B and navigation would take place at a higher level.